# How to send a string from widget to Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have some buttons in my widget that I want to send a intent extra string and also open my Main Activity. This process seems easy enough when it comes from Activity to Activity but I can't make it work from Widget to Activity. I saw some other answers here but I must be missing something because my Logs are not going off.

Here is my updateAppWidget method:

```
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.budget_keeper_widget);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("widget_one", "widget_one");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_1_widget, pendingIntent);


    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

Here's my MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    String intentFromWidget = intent.getStringExtra("widget_one");
    Log.e("WIDGET MAIN INTENT", intentFromWidget);

}
```

This opens my Activity fine but I get no intent extra in my Logs. What's the trick to making this work?

Thank you!

Comment: "I get no intent extra in my Logs" -- replace `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)` with `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried this before and again this time and still nothing in my logs. It opens the MainActivity fine just missing my logs with the newIntent method

Comment: "It opens the MainActivity fine just missing my logs with the newIntent method" -- have you used breakpoints to confirm that `onNewIntent()` is what is being called? Bear in mind that depending on whether the activity exists, and what sort of manifest settings you have, your `PendingIntent` is likely to create a new instance of the activity. If you want to reuse an existing instance if it exists, use flags on the `Intent` like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on breakpoints! Doesn't appear onNewIntent() is being called at all. My manifest has this: 
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>. Maybe this is the wrong way to go about it using this method. I'm stumped.

Comment: Again: you need to do something to cause Android to reuse an existing activity instance. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack and https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation. While the latter is for notifications, the same principles apply here.